# Why can I not see my logs in the azure portal that I can see when debugging locally?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azureportal

I have created an azure function that has a dependency on another project. In this other project I log information that I would like to see in the azure portal when my azure function is running. The name of the class where the function called by my azure function is:
Econtract.Domain.Services.ContractService

I have defined my host.json like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Error",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Econtract": "Information",
      "Econtract.Domain.Services.ContractService": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The logging in "ContractService" is done like this:

```
 _logger.LogInformation("bla bla bla");
```

In the log window in the azure function I can only see the logs that are in the function. Not the ones in the methods called by the function.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might need to add some code so we can see how it actually hangs together.  Pretty hard to diagnose without that.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a work around where first setup azure event hub which will be get logs from azure monitor which is monitoring the current azure function  lets call it function1 (Which itself is being called by other project ) .
Event hub is data streaming platform it will stream this data another function which is event driven let's call it function2.
Now function2 will be triggered by the event hub and it will give to data a storage account .
After this you can retrieve the data from storage account and print it .

refer the following for detailed explanation :

[Collect Logs from Azure Monitor - Sumo Logic](https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Collect-from-Other-Data-Sources/Azure_Monitoring/Collect_Logs_from_Azure_Monitor?msclkid=f99dddc7a5d711ecb2ed3ad086d02c1b)